# How to insert a space between two values in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

My code:

```
$new_user= mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO userinfo (id,firstname,lastname,email,pass,displayname) VALUES ('','$fname','$lname','$email','$db_pass','$fname$lname')");
```

What I want to do:
as you can see in the end of the script that variable `fname` & variable `lname` are supposed to be both inserted in one column, but what I want is a space between those two values.

Explanation:

```
$fname=test;
$lname=tested;
```

I want it inserted in MySQL column like this: `test tested`

Instead, it inserts the values without a space, like this: `testtested`

---

What I've tried:

1. `(....,'$fname.$lname')....` Out comes: `test.tested`
2. `(....,'$fname''$lname')....` Out come: `test'tested`

Help me out please?

Comment: You should consider using prepared statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You literally just need a space between `$fname` and `$lname`, like `$fname $lname`. So, your whole code should look like this:

```
$new_user= mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO userinfo (id,firstname,lastname,email,pass,displayname) VALUES ('','$fname','$lname','$email','$db_pass','$fname $lname')");
```

Also, as @FreshPrinceOfSO says, you should use prepared statements. You have a potential SQL injection problem right now.

Comment: ooooooops sorry ill immediately delete it

Comment: i use mysql escape strings before  inserting them and the reason for storing the values in one column is for the search option im working on

Comment: Then again, all the OP needs to do to show up as a "display name", is to use both column in one echo, and then drop the `displayname` column altogether. @EdCottrell - So you were right after all ;-)

Comment: @ Ed Cottrell i deleted it because i thought it would be a waste of time for other experienced coders to look at

Comment: @Yasin Lots of questions on here involve typos or basic misunderstandings, but that's okay -- if they're redundant, the community will remove them. You only need to delete it if you have an "aha!" moment seconds after posting or something like that.

Comment: Also, if the answer helped you, please consider accepting it. :)

Comment: i can accept it after 2 min due to my deleting & un deleting